# Creating an application that overwrite lock and unlock sound on Android

Tags: android, audio, android-studio, ogg

I want to create an application that is able to override the lock.ogg and unlock.ogg for Android phone without needing to root your phone. But I don't know how to code these properly nor if it's possible programmatically on Android Studio

Here's my basic idea:

1. Perform file searching to obtain all the ogg files stored in the phone.
2. When user has confirmed the sound, the app will copy the file (so that the original file's name is not overwritten), then rename the copied file to lock.ogg/unlock.ogg.

The problem for me is that other than implementing the ogg explorer, I also have to code the destination of the new ogg file to /system/media/audio/ui/ to overwrite the previous lock and unlock sound.

Is this possible using Android Studio?

I'm a newbie on Android Studio.

Comment: I suspect that you might find Android a little more locked down against this kind of thing that you expect.  It sounds a like a great idea for Malware.

Comment: So it's not possible to implement these then?